# Proving $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric is complete

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that every Cauchy space in $\mathbb{R}$ under the discrete metric (I believe this is the correct terminology) is convergent. Here is my attempt:

> Let $\{p_n\}$ be such a Cauchy sequence, so we can  find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n \geq N$, we have $d(p_m, p_n) < 1$, i.e., $d(p_m, p_n) = 0$, in which case $p_m = p_n$ for all $m,n \geq N$, so $\{p_n\}$ is eventually constant. Let $p_n := \alpha$ for all $n \geq N$. Given $\epsilon > 0$, we choose $N$ as above, and notice that for $i,j \geq N$, we have $d(p_i, p_j) < 1$, in which case $p_i = p_j$. Therefore, we in fact have $d(p_i, p_j) = d(\alpha, \alpha) = 0 < \epsilon$. Therefore, $p_n$ converges to $\alpha$, as required. Therefore, $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ is complete.

How does this look?

Comment: Note that there’s nothing special about $\mathbb{R}$ here - this holds for any space with the discrete metric.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and so is the proof. Well, almost. Towards the end, you want to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $d(p_i,\alpha)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

This is what you intended, but you instead write $d(p_i,p_j)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ which is the hypothesis (Cauchy). Instead, the last sentence should be framed somewhat like.

> Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Then there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $$d(p_i,\alpha)=d(\alpha,\alpha)=0<\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, so $(p_n)\to\alpha$.